# Implementation of a generic Stack in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stack

I've implemented a generic `Stack` in C++. I would like a code review in regards to my code, especially on whether or not my implementation satisfy the following 4 points:

1. My Stack class **guarantees** Strong Exception Safety, using the copy and swap idiom
2. The container still works if T passed in is not default constructible
3. Correctness of the implementation of the Rule of Five
4. General implementation correctness and efficiency (i.e: No memory leaks, dangling pointers ... ...)

Additionally, I have also added 4 questions in the code as comments as my concerns in the correctness of my code's implementation/style. I would greatly appreciate if those questions are addressed in the review as well.

```
#pragma once
template <typename T>

class Stack
{
    public:
        Stack();
        Stack(const Stack& other);
        Stack(Stack&& other)                                noexcept;
        ~Stack();

        Stack<T>& operator =(const Stack<T>& other);
        Stack<T>& operator =(Stack<T>&& other)              noexcept;

        void swap(Stack<T>& other)                          noexcept;                   

        friend void swap(Stack<T>& A, Stack<T>& B)
        {
            A.swap(B);
        }

        void pop();
        T& top();
        void push(T item);              //Pass T by value? What if T is big and expensive?

    private:
        struct Node
        {
            Node* next;
            T data;                     //Should data be stored as a reference instead? (i.e: T& data)
        };                              //Should I be adding constructors/destructors and such in this struct?

        Node* head;
        void reverse(Node** head);      //reverse method is not specific to *this stack, should I make it inline or something?
};

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack()
    :head(nullptr)
{}

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack& other)
    :Stack()
{
    Node* curr = other.head;

    while(curr != nullptr)
    {
        push(curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    reverse(&head);
}

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(Stack&& other)          noexcept
    :head(nullptr)
{
    swap(*this, other);
}

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    Node* curr = head;

    while(curr != nullptr)
    {
        Node* tmp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        delete tmp;
    }

    delete head;
}

template <typename T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator =(const Stack<T> &other)
{
    Stack tmp(other);
    swap(*this, tmp);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator =(Stack<T>&& other)    noexcept
{
    swap(*this, tmp);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::swap(Stack& other)               noexcept
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(head, other.head);
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::pop()
{
    if(head == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("No item found in stack");

    Node* curr = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete curr;
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(T item)
{
    Node* tmp = new Node;
    tmp->next = head;
    tmp->data = std::move(item);

    head = tmp;
}

template <typename T>
T& Stack<T>::top()
{
    if(head == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("No item found in stack");

    return head->data;
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::reverse(Node **head)
{
    if(head == nullptr || *head == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("head is null or no head to reverse");

    Node *prev = nullptr;
    Node *next = *head->next;

    while(*head != nullptr)
    {
        *head->next = prev;
         prev = *head;
        *head = next;

        if(next != nullptr)
            next = next->next;
    }

    *head = prev;
}
```

Comment: Did you miss anything here ? `while(curr != nullptr)
        push(curr->data);` you are did notincrement curr and why do you need to `reverse()` ?

Comment: Oh yes i did yes, i meant to do curr = curr->next. Leme fix that woops

Comment: and reverse as well.. you are anyways pushing each item to top... why reversing again ?

Comment: I pushed in the exact opposite direction to other. Suppose other stack contains A->B, I would push other stack into this stack which would look like B->A. I need to reverse the list again to make it look like A->B

Comment: Have you actually tested this? It looks a lot like it should be blowing up in your destructor.

Comment: Please don't edit code in your question after you have received an answer, it invalidates the Q&A nature of the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answers to your questions:

### Should `push` take a value parameter?

Probably not.

As-is, the caller will make a temporary (on the stack), invoke the copy constructor on the temporary, and then `push` will allocate `Node` which includes a `T`, call the default constructor on it, and finally use the move-assignment to fill in `Node.data`. That means you allocate/construct `T` twice (once on the stack and once in `Node`) and reason over the members again in the move-assignment operator. If you're sure the type is small and easily copy-constructed, this is not worth worrying about and allows for more compact code (and a simpler interface). Similarly, if you trust the compiler's optimizer, maybe this isn't worth worrying about.

The simple alternative would be to provide both `const T&` and `T&&` versions of `push` and pass that on to a constructor for `Node` which takes the same type. A more elegant solution would be to take templatized arguments and `std::forward` to `T`'s constructor (when it's made in `Node`). But, maybe then it should be called `emplace`.

### Should `Node.data` be `T&` rather than `T`?

No. This has lifetime and aliasing implications which would violate a reasonably assumed contract for `Stack<T>`. If the calling code wants references, it can specify `Stack<T&>`.

### Should `Stack<T>::Node` have constructors and destructors?

Since the `struct` is private, you should only add those members if the containing code needs it. I think the default destructor will meet your needs, but, for several reasons, you'll want to construct `T.data` and thus you'll need some constructor for `T`.

### `Stack<T>::reverse` is independent of `this*`, how to decorate?

As I'll get to later, I'd recommend eliminating the method entirely, but the direct answer to your question is to use `static`.

## Bugs:

### `head` is deleted twice in destructor

Imagine if you have a single element `Stack`; you'll assign `curr` to that node, notice it's not `nullptr`, set `tmp` to that node, advance `curr` to `nullptr`, `delete` the node, exit the loop, and then try to `delete head`.

### `Stack<T>::push` is not exception safe

If something throws an exception between the `new Node` and the `head = tmp` (especially `T& operator::T(T&& other)`), then you'll leak the Node. You should either wrap the logic in `try`/`catch`/`delete`/`throw` or use a smart pointer (e.g., `std::unique_ptr`) to guarantee cleanup.

```
Node* tmp = nullptr;
try
{
    tmp = new Node;
    // init tmp
}
catch (...)
{
    ::delete tmp;
    throw;
}
```

or

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> tmp(std::make_unique<Node>());
// init tmp
head = tmp.release();
```

### You did not meet your goal #2 regarding no default constructor for `T`

When `Node` is constructed, it implicitly constructs a `T` with the default constructor.

## Efficiency issues:

## Your copy constructor does more work than it needs to.

Just have a Node** which lets you append to the linked list; you don't need to make two passes over the data.

```
Node** dst = &head;
for (Node* src = other.head; src != nullptr; src = src->next)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Node> tmp(std::make_unique<Node>());
    // init tmp

    *dst = tmp.release();
    dst = &(*dst)->next;
}
```

Of course, there is some shared code with `push`; I'll leave it to you to common factor it or, more likely, move the initialization for `tmp` into the constructor.

## Give thought to object-creation overhead.

This was touched on regarding the question about `push` taking a ref.

## Style issues:

### `std::unique_ptr<T>` is a safer alternative than `T*` in most cases

The object referenced by `Stack<T>.head` is "owned" by the `Stack<T>` (it has sole control of lifetime). The same is true for `Stack<T>::Node.next`. Using this and `swap`, you can get a lot more confidence in execption correctness.

However, you'll have a de-facto implementation for your destructor which will be correct but might not be the implementation you'd choose. (The optimizer *might* do the right thing with respect to tail recursion; having confidence in this across compilers and versions requires more validation than I'd personally want to do when I could write an explicit loop to free stuff.)

### use `for` for loops when appropriate.

Your copy constructor looks like an obfuscated `for` loop to me.

### Share code between `pop` and your destructor.

```
while (head != nullptr) pop();
```

### Your move constructor could use the default constructor.

This is a nit-pick, but logicially speaking, you're starting with an empty `Stack<T>` and swapping it with the temporary `Stack<T>&&`.